# In Xamarin Form XAML page, how can I set the width of an Image equal to screen width?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to set the width of an Image to the width of the screen with 20 DP on both sides with the original aspect ratio in a XAML file (Xamarin Form), I hope it can be device-independent, which on any device, the Image width is the same as the screen width with 20 DP on both sides while maintaining its aspect ratio.

I tried WidthRequest, but it doesn't work.

```
    '<Image x:Name="myImgBox" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />'
```

Thank you for the help!

[SCREENSHOT of the PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDFa9.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the HorizontalOptions to FillAndExpand, the image will fill the space available horizontally. You can also change the VerticalOptions.

```
  <Image Source="yourImage.png" 
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
           Aspect="Fill" > </Image>
```

The Aspect property determines how the image will be scaled to fit the display area:

- Fill - Stretches the image to completely and exactly fill the display area. This may result in the image being distorted.
- AspectFill - Clips the image so that it fills the display area while preserving the aspect (ie. no distortion).
- AspectFit - Letterboxes the image (if required) so that the entire image fits into the display area, with blank space added to the top/bottom or sides depending on whether the image is wide or tall.

Comment: So cool, I found more than one similar topics on MS site, but I'm not sure about it. Thank you, let me try.

Comment: But there is another problem that occurred, the image was stretched horizontally, but not vertically, it seems the StackLayout that contains the image is not giving enough space vertically. Would you please help check the screenshot I newly attached in my post (SCREENSHOT of the PROBLEM picture link)? Thanks a lot! I have tried many combinations of HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions for both the parent StackLayout and the Image, none worked.

Comment: If you set a background color on the different stacklayouts, check which one doesnt have enough space. And set the FillAndExpand properties as you see fit

Comment: tried many many combinations, finally got one that works for me :D Thanks a lot!